# Android: exception thrown in one activity is not caught in another activity

Tags: android

I have a ReaderActivity.java class from where I call `signString` in signData.java class. If all is well then a new activity named `ProductActivity` is created. If there is exception in `signString` method, then `ProductActivity` is not supposed to be created.

The issue is, I still see `ProductActivity` is created even though I see the `KSIEXCEPTION` message in the log. What am I missing here?

```
public class ReaderActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
.....
public void setGlobal(String actualData) {
signData sign = new signData();

                try {
                    sign.signString(getBaseContext(), finalResults, countToSend, locToSend, typeToSend);

                    Intent productIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ProductActivity.class);
                    startActivity(productIntent);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

}
}
```

Now in the signData class I have the method

```
public class signData extends Activity{
public void signString(Context context, String data, String count, String loc, String type){

 try {
     /*some http connection code here*/
     /*some computation related to specific API*/
  }
 catch (KSIException e) {
            Log.i("KSIEXCEPTION","here");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}

}
```

Comment: How you know `ProductActivity` is created ? Does it intent to `ProductActivity` ? Also, you have try-catch in both activity. It failed in signData class but pass in ReaderActivity.

Answer (score 0):

1. You cant create object for an activity like this. `signData sign = new signData();`

2.

> The issue is, I still see ProductActivity is created even though I see
>   the KSIEXCEPTION message in the log. What am I missing here?

Yes you just catching the exception in signString method, so after execution of this method definitely, it will create next activity.

If you dont want to go to next activity, you can move that method to some utility class and you can get some return value(boolean at-least) and based on that you can move to next activity